# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to load some comtent in my html page from js.

js code(relevant)-

```
for(i=0; i<4 && 4*i+j<data.response.length; i++)
                {
                    html += '<div class="grids_of_4">';
                    for(j=0; j<4 && 4*i+j<data.response.length; j++)
                    {
                        pi1 = data.response[4*i+j].p_image1;
                        pn = data.response[4*i+j].p_name;
                        pp = data.response[4*i+j].p_price;
                        pa = data.response[4*i+j].p_amount;
                        pid = data.response[4*i+j].p_id;
                        html += "<div class='grid1_of_4'>";
                        html += "<div class='content_box'>";
                        html += "<a href='details.html'>";
                        html += "<div class='view view-fifth'>";
        html += "<img src='/bokaroration/media/" + pi1 + " ' class='img-responsive' alt=''/" + ">";
        html += "<div class='mask'>";
        html += "<div class='info'>Quick View</div></div></a></div>";
        html += "<h4><a href='details.html'> " + pn + "</a></h4>";
        html += "<strike>Rs. " + pp + "</strike>    Rs." + pa;
        html += "<input type='number' id='" + pid + "' min='0' max='100'/" + ">";
        html += "<button type='button' style='margin:5px' class='btn btn-sm btn-success' onclick=add(" + pa + ",'" + pid + "','" + pn + "')"
        html += ">+</button>";
        html += "</div></div>";
                    }
                    html += "</div>";
                    alert(html);
                }
```

and it is alerting correctly but when I click on the button it gives error -

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

and when I checked inspect element I found problem in button tag -

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" rice')="" gate="" onclick="add(180,'qhfghds.;k[','India" style="margin:5px" type="button">

    +

</button>
```

I don't know why it is happening.

Someone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: Because you are constructing HTML by mashing together strings.

You've got an HTML attribute value that is delimited by `'` characters. Inside that value you are putting a `'` without escaping it (as `&#34;`). Since it isn't escaped, it terminates the attribute value.

Use DOM (`createElement`, `setAttribute`, `appendChild`, etc.) instead.